# Add shadow to the collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uicollectionview

I want to develop shadow to my `collectionViewItem` like this:
[image]

How could I achieve this?
I am using a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Hi @matt that duplicate answer you are suggesting didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi @Tanveer! The point is simply that your question is very broad and that the entire matter of how to add a rounded border and shadow to a collection view cell has been dealt with here, in depth, many times before, so that searching would turn up all the info you need. Thus, the new repetition of the question really doesn't need to happen.

Answer (score 1):

- add a view to your cell with left, right, top, and bottom constraint of 5 (or whatever).
- add put all your cell content in that view
- create an outlet for the view
- style:

  ```
  yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5).cgColor
  yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
  yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5).cgColor
  yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
  yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
  ```
- and if you want rounded corners:

  ```
  yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
  ```

Comment: this also helped too. thanks